# Google App Engine - Understanding URLs in deployed mode vrs local - causing Login issues

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url, spring-mvc

I'm new to Google App Engine, and am using it with Spring MVC.  I'm having difficulties with my login functionality and accessing URLs directly.

My login works fine in development mode, but it fails in deployed mode, and it can't find the specified URL.

In my dev mode
   **http://localhost:8888/app/intro.htm** works fine.

However when I try to access it directly via app engine :
   **http://<my app>.appspot.com/app/intro.htm** I get a page can not be found error.

For the login piece, I get an error running the following code in deploy mode only

response.sendRedirect(**userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()**));

Causes an error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The requested URL was not allowed: /app/intro.htm**
    at com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(UserServiceImpl.java:131)

Answer (score 5):

I got tripped up by this too. In my case, it was because I had configured my app's Authentication Options to be restricted to my Google Apps domain.

I resolved this by adding the app id to my Google Apps account. See: [Configuring Google Apps to Authenticate on Appspot](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth#AppspotDomainAuth).

Comment: Yup, that worked. The link is called "Get more apps and services" now and is located left below on the dashboard.

Comment: **2015 Update:** from Admin Console Home (`https://admin.google.com/AdminHome`) click `MORE CONTROLS` at the bottom if `App Engine Apps` is not visible.